# Making speech recognition in C# recognize words from a set vocabulary in continuous speech

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I would like to use speech recognition in my C# application, but so far what I tried has not met my expectations. What I need is a way to recognize words (or maybe very short phrases) from continuous speech without breaks between each word. I am also working with a fairly limited vocabulary and would, therefore, like to limit the options for recognized words to those specified by me.

So far I have tried working with the built-in `System.Speech.Recognition` API. With no vocabulary specified I was able to get it to recognize my voice, but the transcription was not sufficiently accurate for my purposes and it would be also made easier for me in future processing if I could limit the vocabulary.

I then tried specifying a vocabulary, but here the problem with the program skipping words arose. If I speak slowly with a break after each word, it is able to pick up everything just fine and with a seemingly good enough accuracy for my needs. But when I start speaking continuously it usually either only gets the last word or skips some of them.

I also found the `PauseRecognizerOnRecognition` method which seems to be something like what I am looking for. But that only seems to work for `SpeechRecognizer` and not `SpeechRecognitionEngine`. However, for my needs the pop-up and sounds created when using `SpeechRecognizer` are undesirable and I was not able to get it to work properly anyway (I haven't maybe tried enough as I gave up eventually because that will probably not be a suitable solution for me anyway).

What I am looking for is either a way to make this work within the default `System.Speech` library or find some API that would be able to achieve this while working offline and preferably being free.

I have really searched for solutions and tried to get this to work, but I am currently at a loss as to what to do as currently, nothing seems to meet my expectations. Hopefully, somebody can think of a better solution to this problem.

**EDIT:** After giving up due to being unable to find a solution I am now again actively searching for a solution. I managed to get a little further using the built-in Windows' speech recognition with the use of the `Append` method in `GrammarBuilder`. Thanks to this I can now have a set of phrases immediately following each other recognized. One of my issues with this approach is, that depending on the start of the instruction I may expect a different amount of phrases to follow it. The only solution here would be to add all the possible phrases as well as their variations with optional parts at the end. This would not only be tedious but likely very inefficient. For my use case, the phrases I expect to follow differ depending on what precedes them. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any way to recognize the phrases fast enough to be able to say which phrases to expect afterward nor did I find a way to buffer the input waiting for the first part to be recognized and processing the following one based on what is said in the first. I am open to any solutions including the use of other APIs.